# I want to know how to control this card reader devices through application any code which i can use or example which help me

Tags: android, credit-card, cardreader

I have one credit or debit card reader device and that device will communicate with only with host application that device is MAGTEK uDynamo i want to know how to communicate with this device through android app any example or  suggestions please suggest me. Please

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can get the Programmer's Reference Manual for the device here:
https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875723.pdf

You can also find the quick installation guide here:
https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875312.pdf

But, **getting more to the crux of the issue**, you can easily start writing applications for Android by using **[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)** (which is a simple way of writing Android appls with HTML, CSS and Javascript), and then you can **use this package to communicate with the MAGTEK uDynamo:** **https://github.com/CODESM003/uDynamo-Phonegap-Android**

*good luck, and happy programming!*